# MySQL - Can't use GROUP_CONCAT and filter results

Tags: mysql, join

Hi have the following database schema:

```
items
- id
- item_name

items_cats
- item_id
- cat_id

categories
- id
- cat_name
```

From now, I can select the items and categories in a single query like that:

```
SELECT i.id, i.item_name, GROUP_CONCAT(c.cat_name) as cats
FROM items AS i, items_cats AS ic, categories AS c
WHERE ic.item_id = i.id AND ic.cat_id = c.id
GROUP BY i.id
```

This result something like this:

```
id| item_name | cats
1 | Item 1    | Cat 1, Cat 2
2 | Item 2    | Cat 1
3 | Item 3    | Cat 3, Cat 5
4 | Item 4    | Cat 2, Cat 3, Cat 4
```

Now I need the same result, but I want only the records containing "Cat 3". If I add "c.id = 3" in WHERE clause, results in this:

```
id| item_name | cats
3 | Item 3    | Cat 3
4 | Item 4    | Cat 3
```

But I want the other categories from the item, like this:

```
id| item_name | cats
3 | Item 3    | Cat 3, Cat 5
4 | Item 4    | Cat 2, Cat 3, Cat 4
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. Just added the following in the end of query:

```
HAVING cats LIKE CONCAT('%', (SELECT cat_name FROM categories WHERE id = 3), '%')
```

Answer (score 0):

First, learn to use proper `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause; *always* use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax with the join conditions in the `ON` clause.

Second, you can do this using a simple predicate in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT i.id, i.item_name, GROUP_CONCAT(c.cat_name SEPARATOR ', ') as cats
FROM items i JOIN
     items_cats ic 
     ON  ic.item_id = i.id JOIN
     categories c
     ON ic.cat_id = c.id
GROUP BY i.id
HAVING MAX(c.cat_name = 'Cat 3') > 0;
```

Your separator appears to have a space in it.

If you want to do this by id, then use:

```
HAVING MAX(c.id = 3) > 0;
```